# Presented a paper in a conference, but my paper did not get published in proceeding

Tags: conference

I presented a paper in a conference, but my paper did not get published in the proceedings. The authority said my paper was submitted late and could not be reviewed and therefore it was not published in the proceedings. However I was called to present my research paper and got a certificate also saying that I presented the paper in that conference.
But the issue is my paper did not get indexed/published. 
I am worried about the fate of my paper now. What should I do ?
Can I give it for publication at some better place?

Comment: What field are you in? Customs regarding conferences vary widely between fields.

Comment: As a general rule, if your paper hasn't been published, then you are free to publish it.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you - and if I could publish that research in a peer review magazine, in your situation - I would do so. If your research didn't make it to proceedings (for whatever reason), it is open for subsequent submissions. It is practically same situation when your paper is rejected in a journal - you can re-submit it elsewhere.

Now - is it justified to submit that same talk for some other conference where it has not been published (in a journal)? - thats dubious and might be frowned upon depending on the size and praxis of your field, but I believe submitting it to a journal is pretty much ok.